# How often shoud a file be opened and closed when constantly writing data to a file (SDCard)?

Tags: c, file, sd-card

I am developing a CAN-BUS logger with an ESP32. The data is written to a SDCard with fprintf.

I know I have to use fopen() to open the file and later fclose() to close the file again.

**My question is how often should I open and close the file? Open it just one time and then maybe an hour later close it? Or open it, write 100 values, close it, open it again?**

I don't want to lose a lot of data. The ESP32 will be on when the motorcycle with the CAN-BUS is running. And if the ignition is turned off then the ESP32 will have no power anymore. I don't mind if maybe data from the last 5 seconds is lost. But I don't want that i.e. 10 minutes of data is lost.

**I also saw the fflush() function. Should I use that regularly i.e. every 10 seconds? And then maybe it's no problem if the file is never closed?**

More info: I could design the device to make sure the power is on long enough so that fclose() is executed (no power failure before that). But I guess this is not really necessary if I don't mind that the last seconds of data is lost.

I put this question into StackOverflow and not electrical engineering because this is about writing the code for that project.

I searched and found similar questions here but I did not really find an answer to this question.

Comment: You can open and close the file how many times you like. You have only consider the execution overhead to open/close files. The best solution can be to buffer data of the time you can loose, 5 seconds, and each 5 seconds update the file. There could be other techniques on big systems, but your should be an embedded application, than the file system code is functionally limited I suppose.

Comment: Does the ESP32 chip have support for a brownout interrupt? If you have the supporting hardware to guarantee power for a certain duration, calling `fclose()` in the brownout interrupt might be a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux manpage for `fflush` includes a really important warning:

> NOTES
>   Note  that  fflush()  flushes only the user-space buffers provided by the C library. To ensure that the data is physically stored on disk the kernel buffers must be flushed too, for example, with `sync(2)` or `fsync(2)`.

`sync` or `fsync` are part of the Posix interface, which might or might not be similar to the underlying file i/o interfaces on your ESP32. But the warning is probably still worth heeding.

The C standard has this wording for `fflush`, which makes it clear that all that is guaranteed is that `fflush` flushes out the buffers maintained by the C library, similar to the wording in the Linux manpage:

> … the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file…

So if you want data to be actually committed to disk, `fflush` is not generally sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests to answer my question.

First I used this code:

```
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Opening file");
FILE* f = fopen(fileName1, "a");
if (f == NULL) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open file for append");
    return;
}
int64_t t = 0;
for (unsigned long i = 1; i <= 10009000; i++)
{
    t = esp_timer_get_time();
    fprintf(f, "%010" PRId64, t);
    fprintf(f, " ");
    fprintf(f, "%10lu\n", i);

    if (0 == i % 10000){
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Flush file");
        fflush(f);
    }
}
//fclose(f);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File written");
```

Please notice that the file is never closed.

When I run that code on my ESP32 the file is created but nothing is written to the file. So at least with my configuration fclose() is necessary.

When I change the code to this:

```
for (unsigned long i = 1; i <= 109000; i++)
{
    t = esp_timer_get_time();
    fprintf(f, "%010" PRId64, t);
    fprintf(f, " ");
    fprintf(f, "%10lu\n", i);

    if (0 == i % 10000){
        //fflush(f);
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Close and Open file");
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen(fileName1, "a");
    }
}
//fclose(f);
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File written");
```

then the data is written to the file. In this case the last line in the file is

0013521402     100000

So as expected the values after 100,000 (the last time when the file was closed) and before 109,000 (i <= 109000) are not written to the file.

**My conclusion is: I have to use fclose(). The program does not write anything if I just use fflush() regularly. How often I have to close and open the file depends on how much data I am prepared to lose. For my application I will decide this later after some testing. Maybe I will close and open the file i.e. every 5 seconds. Or I will do this after writing 1000 lines or something like this.**